# mysql innodb basic design for joomla component

Tags: mysql, joomla, foreign-keys, innodb

I have four entities:

- person
- center
- activity
- address

So my idea is:

- A person may have an associated address.
- A center may have an associated address.
- An activity may have an associated address.

Is this mysql design correct for a joomla component?

```
CREATE TABLE `#__person` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
other fields...
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `#__center` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
other fields...
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `#__activity` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
other fields...
PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `#__address` (
`id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`line1` varchar(30),
`line2` varchar(30),
`locality` varchar(10),
`region` varchar(10),
`country` varchar(10),
`postcode` varchar(10),
`person_id` int(10),
`center_id` int(10),
`activity_id` int(10),
PRIMARY KEY (id),
FOREIGN KEY `person_id` REFERENCES `#__person` (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY `center_id` REFERENCES `#__center` (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
FOREIGN KEY `activity_id` REFERENCES `#__activity` (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
other fields...
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

So i.e:

- If I delete a person, automatically his/her corresponding address will be deleted?
- And if I delete an address, what will happen to their references? (hope nothing)
- What happens if the same address is an address for a center and for an activity?
- Are the foreign keys in the correct table or should i put an address_id field in person,center and activity?

I'm a bit confused about my design.

Thank you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of placing an id for person, center and activity into the address table, I would suggest placing an address_id into each of the other tables (person, center, and activity). Then, you could reuse the same address across the other tables and in different combinations of person, center, and activity.

And about cascade, I think the [MySQL Reference manual explains it well](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html):

> CASCADE: Delete or update the row from the parent table, and
>   automatically delete or update the matching rows in the child table.
>   Both ON DELETE CASCADE and ON UPDATE CASCADE are supported. Between
>   two tables, do not define several ON UPDATE CASCADE clauses that act
>   on the same column in the parent table or in the child table.

So if you did change address_id to be in each of the other tables and then you applied the foreign key constraint

```
FOREIGN KEY `address_id` REFERENCES `#__address` (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
```

then when you deleted the row in the address table (the one WITHOUT the foreign key constraint), the matching rows in either person, center, or activity (where the foreign keys are defined), would be deleted. BUT, I am guessing that this might not be what you want, because you said a person, center and activity "may" have an address. So if you deleted the address, you do not necessarily want to delete the person, center or activity that was using that address. If that is true, then I would change your foreign key constraint in each of the 3 tables to:

```
FOREIGN KEY `address_id` REFERENCES `#__address` (id) ON DELETE SET NULL
```